# How to debug my C++ program?

Tags: c++

I try to enter 2d array and to sum all numbers in one row. Then I convert that number to binary (8 bit) and to set it again in new 2d array. Here's my code. I get output in negative numbers and I expect binary number.

I input

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

And i want this output

00000110

00001111

00011000

i get

00000000

00000000

00000000

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m,j,i;
    int a[50][50],b[50][8],c[50];
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        c[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cin>>a[i][m];
            cin.ignore();
            c[i]+=a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            b[i][j]=c[i]%2;
            c[i]/=2;
        }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            cout<<b[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1. _`int a[n][m],b[n][8],c[n],bin[8];`_ Standard c++ doesn't support variable length arrays, use `std::vector<int>` instead. 2. Move initialization after the `cin>>n>>m;`

Comment: Execution of the program is, in the absence of loops, from top to bottom. You define arrays with the size set as zero, those definitions won't be retroactively defined once you read into the variables `n` and `m`.

Comment: Not even that emoji will save you from learning harder.

Comment: What's point in negative vote me when you don't help. And that's why this exist. I changed code, now i only get 0.Help?

Comment: You get downvotes because you seem to have not  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit your question to include the input that causes the problem, as well as the expected and actual output. It would also help if you could step through the code in a debugger, line by line, to better be able to tell us where you think the problem is (unless you find it yourself). Stackoverflow.com is not a debugger-as-a-service.

Comment: @Some _"the size set as zero"_ Not guaranteed, though.

Comment: I add all that things. Can you now help me and un dislike my post.

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic Your edit wasn't really helpful.

Comment: Here try now.:D

Comment: What's the purpose of the `a` array? You never use it for anything except an attempt at temporary storage (watch your indexing closely).

Comment: That's my input array.

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic If you replace the loop body with `int x; cin >> x; c[i] += x;` at least one bug will disappear. (You're not adding the number you read, and you only need one number.)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to revise your code but I soon realised that you were doing some weird unnecessary things so I just started fresh and here's what I've got for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void add_array(int arr1[], int arr2[], int arrLength, int ret[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        ret[i] = arr1[i]+arr2[i];
    }
    return;
}

void to_binary(int n, vector<int> *ret) {
    while(n!=0) {
        ret->push_back(n%2==0 ?0:1);
        n/=2;
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[5] = {6,7,8,9,10};
    int c[5];
    add_array(a, b, 5, c);
    cout << "A:" << endl;   
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << i << " : " << a[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "B:" << endl;   
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << i << " : " << b[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "C:" << endl;   
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << i << " : " << c[i] << endl;
    }
    vector<int> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        to_binary(c[i], &vec);
        for(int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++) {
            cout << vec[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        vec.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how you were handling the adding of the two functions so I just wrote a really simple function there, I'll start with the parameters

```
int arr1[], int arr2[]
```

These are the two functions you'll be adding, simple.

```
int arrLength
```

This tells the function what the length of the two arrays is for the 'for loop'

```
int ret[]
```

Ret is the return array and is passed in so that it can be modified with the added arrays, now you could do that with either of the other two arrays but this is better practice especially if you want to reuse the other arrays later.

Now here's the function itself

```
for(int i=0;i<arrLength;i++){ ret[i]=arr1[i]+arr2[i];}
```

Here we loop through each position in the arrays and place them in the variable 'ret', this is the whole thing.

The function

```
void to_binary(int n, vector<int> *ret)
```

handles the decimal to binary using a vector for variable sizes, it's basically what you were doing just in a function.

In the function ***main*** we create the three arrays and call ***add_array*** with the necessary arguments, then we create the vector ***vec*** and then proceed to loop through the array ***c*** getting the binary number of each position and then since we stored the binary number in an ***int vector*** instead of a string we loop through the vector

```
for(int j = 0; j < vector.size(); j++)
```

We are using ***vector.size()*** to get the dynamic size of the vector, then we print out each binary digit and then print an ***endl*** and clear the vector for reuse.